# Including specific jquery only for one snippet

Tags: jquery

It may be a stupid question, but since i am a complete newbie, dont blame me :)

Site i am working on is using old version of jQuery (1.7.2), and i need 2.1.3 for small menu snippet.If i include 2.1.3 in the footer (or header), some functionalities on the site stop working so i need to stick with that older version.

So, i was wondering is it possible to include 2.1.3 inside the script tag and limit it only for this specific snippet (the one bellow)?

```
<script>
    $('.navigation a').click(function() {
      var $requested = $(this.getAttribute('href'));
      $('.top-drawer').not($requested).slideUp('slow');
      $requested.slideToggle('slow')
    });
</script>
```

Comment: You need to look at `jQuery.noConflict()`

Comment: i am totally new at this, but when i include noConflict at the beginning on this script, it completely stops working

Answer (score 0):

The solution is no make use of [jQuery.noConflict()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/).

After including jQuery2, you need to place all the scripts that need to work with jQuery2, after that you can call `noConflict()`, but if you want to make use of jQuery2 later you can use the value returned by `noConflict()` as shown below.

```html
<script src="//tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#test').click(function() {
      snippet.log('clicked 1: ' + $.fn.jquery)
    })
  });
</script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#test').click(function() {
      snippet.log('clicked 2: ' + $.fn.jquery)
    })
  });
</script>
<script>
  var jq2 = jQuery.noConflict(true)
</script>
<script>
  jq2(function($) {
    $('#test').click(function() {
      snippet.log('clicked 3: ' + $.fn.jquery)
    })
  });
</script>
<script>
  jQuery(function($) {
    $('#test').click(function() {
      snippet.log('clicked 4: ' + $.fn.jquery)
    })
  });
</script>

<button id="test">Test</button
```